# Print matched token in JavaCC

Tags: javacc

I need to print the token that was matched by javacc, but I don't know how to "store it".
Let's say my token definition is:

```
TOKEN :
{
    < BLAH: ["0"-"9"]> 
}
```

and my parser.input() function is:

```
void Input():
{}
{ (<BLAH> { System.out.println("I recognize BLAH"); } ) 
}
```

However what I really want to output, given some input, let's say 5, is:

```
I recognize that BLAH is 5.
```

Any tips? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you declare variables in the first curly braces and use them in the second:

```
void Input():
{ Token t;   }
{ 
   (t=<BLAH> { System.out.println("I recognize BLAH is "  + t.image); } ) 
}
```